# how can I format string literal hex opcodes?

Tags: python

I am trying to save my addreses as `\\xfc\\x41\\x41\\x41\\x41\\x41\\x41\\x41` , but I dont know how to achieve which translate to `\xfc\x41`

```
ret = "41414141414141"
for byte in range(0, 256):
    print "0x{:02x}".format(byte) + ret
    with open('rets','w') as rets:
        rets.write("0x{:02x}".format(byte) + ret)
```

Comment: One problem is that you are opening the file on every iteration of your `for` loop. This is overwriting the file on every iteration. You should move the `with` statement outside of the loop. It's also confusing that your code is prepending the numbers with `0x`, but your text refers to `\\x` as the prefix. Which do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what the purpose is but I can help with the formatting.

```py
ret = "41414141414141"

# Translate the string to include the \x in chunks of 2
translated = ["\\x" + ret[idx:idx+2] for idx in range(0, len(ret), 2)]
assert translated == ["\\x41", "\\x41", "\\x41", "\\x41", "\\x41", "\\x41", "\\x41"]

# Build the final string by joining the elements
value = "\\xfc" + "".join(translated)
assert value == "\xfc\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41"
```

This example is using Python list comprehensions. The assert statements are to should what is expected after each step and can be removed.

A version using a for loop:

```py
for idx in range(0, len(ret), 2):
    byte = ret[idx:idx+2]
    print("\\x" + byte)
```

You will also want to move your open block outside of the loop, each time you open a file this way you will cause it to overwrite the previous entry.